# No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers when using uni_form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to use uni_form with Django 2.1.5 latest version.

and after importing `from uni_form.helper import FormHelper` in the forms.py

an error message says :

> File
>   "D:\installed_apps\python\lib\site-packages\uni_form\helper.py", line
>   1, in 
>       from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, NoReverseMatch ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers'

However, after looking arround in stackoverflow I came up with change the helper.py  :

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, NoReverseMatch
```

to :

```
from django.urls import reverse, NoReverseMatch
```

another problem rises :

> File
>   "D:\installed_apps\python\lib\site-packages\uni_form\helper.py", line
>   4, in 
>       from utils import render_field ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

django-uni-form has not been developed for years. As [the project page](https://github.com/pydanny-archive/django-uni-form) says, you should use [django-crispy-forms](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms) instead.

Comment: I was having troubles with crispy form so i thought that i could shift to uni_form , hope you can help me with it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101476/crispy-forms-and-bootstrap-styles

Comment: I can't help you with that question, but switching to uni_form isn't the answer.

Comment: I didn't notice the first line on their documentation but I'll shift back to crispy , thanks